# Как разместить два графика mathplotlib в двух разных виджетах?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Нужно разместить два графика mathplotlib в главном GUI окне . Один тип графика гистограмма, другой полярная диаграмма. В QtDesigner создал два MplWidgeta (Фрагмент кода ниже)

```
    self.mplwidget_hist = MplWidget(self.page)
    self.mplwidget_hist.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(798, 8, 169, 533))
    self.mplwidget_hist.setObjectName("mplwidget_hist")
    self.widget_polar = MplWidget(self.page)
    self.widget_polar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(448, 216, 345, 323))
    self.widget_polar.setObjectName("widget_polar")
    from mplwidget import MplWidget
```

Создал класс, но нет понимания как добавить график  гистограммы.

```
class MplWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
        
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

При выводе отображается две полярные диаграммы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно их прописать в классе, и сделать их независимыми?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен созданием отдельного класса для виджета с графиком гистограммы.

```
class MplWidget_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111, polar=True)  #polar
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)

class MplWidget_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111) #hist
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]